# set SIM as a default SIM to send SMS message and make a call in android programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application which makes a call and sends SMS messages, but I don't want to ask the user each time to choose one SIM to send SMS messages through it, so I want to ask the user to enter his phone number (number of one SIM) and make it default to make a call and send SMS in this application without asking him again to choose which SIM he wants. so How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        SubscriptionManager subs = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        if (subs != null) {
            Log.d("sim_spalsh", "num sims = " + subs.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax());

            if (subs.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCountMax() > 1) {

                //SendSMS From SIM One
                SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(0)
                        .sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "sim1", null, null);

                //SendSMS From SIM Two
                SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(1)
                        .sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "sim2", null, null);

            }
        }
    }
```

Give permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: and if I want to send it from SIM which has the same number which user entered ? for example user entered number 011111 I want to send msg from SIM which has this number, how can I do ?

Comment: There us noway you can detect phone number programmatically